# How to display the images in phonegap from server response

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have a signature pad in my server when posted the values from server to my phonegap application i get the response like below how to use that response to store into DB and display in my phonegap.

My response after parsing JSON:

```
[{"searchStr":"signature.png:sStrEnd","type":"image\/png","usrName":"signature.png","size":5686,"name":"files\/x5cviyfvqelfbra.png"}]
```

in that response how can i get the image path or direct images.

my script for display the image in canvas

```
var arbeidcanvas = $('#mArbeid')[0];
    arbeidcanvas.width = arbeidcanvas.width;
    var arbeidsign = arbeidcanvas.getContext("2d");
    var arbeidimg = new Image();
    arbeidimg.src = **MYDATABASE VALUE**;
    arbeidimg.onload = function() {
         arbeidsign.drawImage(arbeidimg, 0,0);
    }
```

Comment: what you have tried to store response in db?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK my respone is stored in my DB.. i don't understand the response it is automatically generated in phprunner.

Comment: response string is JSONArray so you will first need to parse then store all values in db

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK after parsing only i get the above result...

Comment: look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/9991872/2567813

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="result_data"></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 var obj = [{"searchStr":"signature.png:sStrEnd","type":"image\/png","usrName":"signature.png","size":5686,"name":"files\/x5cviyfvqelfbra.png"}] ;    
if(obj.length >0){
    var list = '<ul data-role="listview" >'
     $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        if(value.searchStr){
            list += '<li>searchStr :'+value.searchStr+'</li>';
        }
        if(value.type)
           list += '<li>type :'+value.type+'</li>';
        if(value.size)
            list += '<li>size :'+value.size+'</li>';
        if(value.name)
            list += '<li>name :'+value.name+'</li>';
     }) ;
     list += '</ul>' ;
     $("#result_data").append(list).trigger('create');
     $("#result_data").listview('refresh');

     var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = your_img_src;


 }
});
</script>
```

Store data in db see this link

1) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

Comment: for your knoledge to display json data on phonegap

Comment: you can simply store object in window.localStorage and use it

Comment: Simply you should store only image path of server.  Because mobile has limted memory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43408/discussion-between-ved-and-ela)

Comment: i stored in DB files/s3fngaj74y37jgk.png i want to show this in my canvas tag ...please help me to do this..

Answer (score -1):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(myMessage);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.counters.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.counters[i];
    console.log(counter.counter_name);
}
```