# Parsing JSON array of objects: undefined property

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

So, similar to my my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247130/parsing-an-external-json-with-an-array-and-saving/31247435#31247435) (I was unsure whether to make a new question or edit the old one), I managed to sucessfully parse the `body` JSON response using the code seen below.

However when attempting to do the same to the `event_calendar_date`, I get this: `Failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'und' of undefined`. I would have assumed that to get to the next object in the array the method would be the same for both, however that does not appear to be the case.

JSON response from the server:

```
[

    {
        "revision_uid":"1",
        "body":{
            "und":[
                {
                    "value":"Blah Blah.",
                    "summary":"",
                    "format":null,
                    "safe_value":"Blah Blah.",
                    "safe_summary":""
                }
            ]
        },
        "event_calendar_date":{
            "und":[
                {
                    "value":"2015-07-20 14:00:00",
                    "value2":"2015-07-20 20:00:00",
                    "timezone":"America/New_York",
                    "timezone_db":"America/New_York",
                    "date_type":"datetime"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

]
```

My Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: 'http://www.scolago.com/001/articles/views/articles',
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        var data = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        var articles = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var Articles = Parse.Object.extend("Articles"),
                article = new Articles(),
                content = data[i];

            article.set("body", content.body.und[0].value);
            article.set("vid", content.vid);
            article.set("title", content.title);

            article.set("events", content.event_calendar_date.und[0].value);

            articles.push(article);
        };


        // function save(articles);
        Parse.Object.saveAll(articles, {
            success: function(objs) {
                promise.resolve();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                promise.reject(error.message);
            }
        });

    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        promise.reject(error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do a console.log on var data, that will show you in the inspector the structure of the data then you can see what it has. This will help you debug the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you didn't give us all code, or you are using not the code you posted in this question, because it should run fine, as you can see [in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nkqtwbbj/1/):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var content = data[i];
    console.log(content.event_calendar_date.und[0].value);
};
```

## EDIT and solution

As I expected, JSON you are getting doesn't have field `event_calendar_date` for 2nd, and 3rd object. I checked in your [full code on GitHub.](https://github.com/Scolago/CloudCode/blob/master/cloud/main.js)

First object has correct `event_calendar_date` field, but next records don't have. See how is JSON you are getting formatted - http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b46878adcffe92f53f689978873a3474.

You need to check first if `content.event_calendar_date` is present in record in your current loop iteration or add `event_calendar_date` to ALL records in JSON response.

Comment: Well [here](https://github.com/Scolago/CloudCode/blob/master/cloud/main.js) is the full code if you think it will help. But afaik, I posted all relevant code.

Comment: I dont believe I will be able to change the JSON response, so would a simple if statement to check for `content.event_calendar_date` be suitable for the task? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455338/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-key-in-javascript.