# How we can get json array value in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "test2.php",
        data : $("#tab"),
        type : "GET",
        success : function(b){
                      b = eval('('+ b +')');    
                      console.log((b['t']));
                      alert(b);
                  }
    });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: you can use JSON.parse - almost same question here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use eval(). You can either set the data type on the request as JSON or use JSON.parse();

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "test2.php",
        data : $("#tab"),
        type : "GET",
        success : function(b){
                      b = JSON.parse(b);    
                      console.log((b['t']));
                      alert(b);
                  }
    });
});

//datatype as JSON

$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "test2.php",
        data : $("#tab"),
        type : "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(b){   
                      console.log((b['t']));
                      alert(b);
                  }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data using "parseJSON"

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "test2.php",
        data : $("#tab"),
        type : "GET",
        success : function(b){
                 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(b);
                 console.log(obj);

                }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery, try this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "test2.php",
        data : $("#tab"),
        type : "GET",
        success : function(b){
            var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(b);
            alert(obj.<name>);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: am using value in json

Comment: And after I want get value in Ajax on next page

Comment: Could you provide some values of your json? Btw in the following code, `obj.<name>` change `<name>` to your key.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AJAX, you can directly set the dataType as json and no need to again parse the data.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url : "test2.php",
    data : $("#tab"),
    dataType : "json",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(b){
                  // b is in the JSON format, print the complete JSON
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(b));    
                  console.log(b['t']);
                  alert(b);
              }
  });
});
```