# Parse result of API response that looks like JSON array (of type string) back into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

How can we convert an array of type string back into array.

```
var arr = '[ "abc", "def"]';
console.log(typeof arr)    ==> String
```

How can i convert it back into an array?

I am getting this array in form of string from an API response. and these are errors which can be multiple. I want to convert them into an array such that i can display them on their correct positions.

Comment: When programming, it's important to always ask why you're doing what you're doing. `JSON.parse(arr)`. But, why is `arr` a String in the first place? My guess... bad practice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Corrected that.

Comment: I think @PHPglue is saying something along the lines of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/293552).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript how to parse JSON array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array)

Answer (score 0):

**If** your string is really as shown in your edit (not your original question), it's valid JSON, so you could use `JSON.parse`:

```
var str = '["abc", "def"]';
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your array syntax conforms to that of a [JSON array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse): Use a JSON parser.

Browsers have one built-in these days.

```
arr = JSON.parse(arr);
```

For a more general approach, you would need to look at [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but that has numerous drawbacks (including issues of scope, speed, and security).

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert it back, since you don't actually have an array.

an array should be created without the single quotes ... you are creating a string, you want to do something like the following if you want to create an array.

```
var arr = ["string 1","string 2"];
```

**UPDATE**
Since you updated your question, with information regarding why you had a string, you can follow the suggested solution:

```
JSON.parse(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** to convert the `JSON string` into `JSON object`.

**DEMO**

```js
var arr = '[ "abc", "def"]';
console.log(typeof arr); // string

var arr = JSON.parse('[ "abc", "def"]');
console.log(typeof arr); // object
```