# Get values from JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to get values from a JSONString using javaScript. I did the following :

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
var jsonVar = "jVar";


for (var l = 0; l < jsonData.jsonVar.length; l++) {
                    var item = jsonData.itemI+"-"+itemJ+"-"+itemK.split(' ').join('')[i];
                    alert(cuecard);
                }
```

Here is the JSONData:

```
{"jVar":["123","234"]}
```

But i am getting the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.success (test.jsp:62)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

I saw the example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array) and i dont know the mistake i am doing.Can any one please suggest.

Comment: it's `JSON.parse()` not `stringify()`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` if for converting a value into a JSON string. If you want to parse a JSON string, use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: What are you trying to do with that 'itemI', 'itemJ', and 'itemK' stuff? That doesn't resemble your data at all.

Answer (score 2):

You have it the wrong way round - `JSON.stringify` turns a javascript object to a string. And `JSON.parse` parses a JSON String to a javascript object.

Also, having done that, if you want to read a property using a string use square bracket notation:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
var jsonVar = "jVar";

for (var l = 0; l < jsonData[jsonVar].length; l++) {
  var arrayItem = jsonData[jsonVar][l];
 ...
}
```

(As an aside `l` is a bad choice for a loop control variable - looks too much like a `1`)

Comment: It still has another issue with the property accessor.

Comment: @epascarello yes, I saw that too. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the proprty like this.

```
for (var l = 0; l < jsonData[jVar].length; l++) {

}
```

Comment: Still has another issue with the first line of the OPs code

Comment: Yeah is see there are other issues. e.g "jsonData.itemI" itmel is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a valid JSON object first. I don't think what you have is valid to start with.

```
JSON.parse(yourValidJsonObject);
```

The above should give you a plain Javascript object you can work with.

Whereas, `JSON.stringify(yourPlainJavascriptObject)` will turn the plain js object to a JSON object.

Answer (score -1):

Simply run JSON.parse(jsonString) to get an object from it