# Convert string of coordinates into an array for polygon coordinates using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-map

I have a string with a list of coordinates that I need to convert into an array. I tried to do let array = Array(coordinates) but itusing parsebut doesnt work.
The string I am trying to convert looks like this:

```
var coordinates="[[-118.284211,34.083625],[-118.27955,34.090733],[-118.277162,34.095776],[-118.275638,34.095363],[-118.266013,34.09563],[-118.260969,34.10031],[-118.260623,34.098253],[-118.264394,34.091552],[-118.260434,34.090493]]"
```

I need to remove the double quotes and it would be like this

```
[[[-118.284211,34.083625],[-118.27955,34.090733],[-118.277162,34.095776],[-118.275638,34.095363],[-118.266013,34.09563],[-118.260969,34.10031],[-118.260623,34.098253],[-118.264394,34.091552],[-118.260434,34.090493]]].
```

In this way it will work on kendo map. Thanks!!

Comment: Just do a `JOSN.parse(coordinates)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript how to parse JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array)

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
var output = [ JSON.parse( coordinates ) ]
```

**Explanation :**

- Parse JSON to get internal 2-dimensional array.
- Wrap the output of `JSON.parse` into another array.

Comment: I already tried this but no luck . suppose my string is : var str="[[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]" ; JSON.parse(str); it will result -Array(3)
0
:
(2) [0, 1]
1
:
(2) [1, 0]
2
:
(2) [1, 1]
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0) . but what my need is [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] array with commas