# Parse JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a service called UserService that returns the roles of the logged in user.

It returns either
`[{"authority":"ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT"},{"authority":"ROLE_APEX_READONLY"}]` or `[{"authority":"ROLE_APEX_READONLY"}]`.

I want to do something when I see that the response returned has `ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT` authority in it.
How do I parse the response to identify that?

```
let listOfAuthorities = this.userServices.getAuthorities();
```

`listOfAuthorities` is an array of JSON of above mentioned response.
How do I parse and see if it has Support role in response?

Comment: `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript how to parse JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether your data contains `ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT`:

```
const json = [{"authority":"ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT"}, {"authority":"ROLE_APEX_READONLY"}];
const isROLE_APEX_SUPPORT = json.some(s=>s.authority === 'ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT');
console.log(isROLE_APEX_SUPPORT); // Output: true
```

To find whether your data contains `ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT`:

```
const json = [{"authority":"ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT"}, {"authority":"ROLE_APEX_READONLY"}];
const roleAlexSupport = json.find(s=>s.authority === 'ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT');
console.log(roleAlexSupport ); // OUTPUT: {authority: "ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT"}
```

In addition, you can [use json.parse() method to parse JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do something when I see that the response returned has ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT authority in it

If I understand your question correctly, you probably want to check if your array has an item with `authority: ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT`

```js
const input1 = [{
  "authority": "ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT"
}, {
  "authority": "ROLE_APEX_READONLY"
}];

const input2 = [{
  "authority": "ROLE_APEX_READONLY"
}];

function hasAuthority(input, authority) {
  return input.some((i) => i.authority === authority);
}

console.log(hasAuthority(input1, "ROLE_APEX_READONLY"))
console.log(hasAuthority(input2, "ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT"))
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little effort you could have found the answer yourself. But, here it is:

```
let listOfAuthorities = this.userServices.getAuthorities();
let authorityList = JSON.parse(listOfAuthorities);

authorityList.forEach(authority => {
    if(authority.authority === 'ROLE_APEX_SUPPORT') {
    // write your logic here
    }
});
```