# How to find length of array of sets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

My Json response from servicenow is as follows:

*** Script:

```
[ 
   { 
      "errno":"0",
      "num_keys":"0",
      "ipmdns_hsm_enabled":"0",
      "ipmdns_protocol":"https",
      "ipmdns_type":"named",
      "dns_force_hybrid":"0",
      "gss_keytab_id":"0",
      "use_update_policy":"0",
      "dnszone_synching":"0",
      "dns_state":"Y",
      "vdns_parent_id":"0",
      "dnszone_allow_update":"admin;",
      "dnszone_allow_query":"",
      "dnszone_allow_transfer":"",
      "dnszone_forwarders":"",
      "dnszone_forward":"default",
      "dnszone_notify":"",
      "dnszone_also_notify":"",
      "dnszone_name_utf":"amec.com",
      "dnszone_id":"31704",
      "row_enabled":"1",
      "dns_type":"ipm",
      "dns_cloud":"0",
      "dnszone_ad_integrated":"0",
      "dnszone_sort_zone":"amec.iras-tp.com",
      "dns_id":"6",
      "dns_name":"dnscom",
      "dnszone_name":"amec.iras-tp.com",
      "dnszone_rev_sort_zone":"com.iras-tp.amec",
      "dnszone_is_rpz":"0",
      "dnszone_type":"master",
      "dnszone_masters":"",
      "dnszone_xfer_done":"Y",
      "dnszone_is_reverse":"0",
      "delayed_delete_time":"0",
      "delayed_create_time":"0",
      "dnszone_order":"0",
      "dnszone_site_name":"Gen",
      "dnszone_site_id":"3",
      "dnszone_class_name":"",
      "dnsview_name":"#",
      "dnsview_id":"0",
      "dnsview_class_name":"",
      "dns_class_name":"",
      "dns_comment":"Niewegein NL-213 ",
      "dns_version":"BIND 9.11.8",
      "vdns_parent_name":"#",
      "ds":"",
      "ip_addr":"fghjj",
      "multistatus":"",
      "dnszone_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source":"ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
      "dnsview_class_parameters":"",
      "dnsview_class_parameters_properties":"",
      "dns_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dns_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
   },
   { 
      "errno":"0",
      "num_keys":"0",
      "ipmdns_hsm_enabled":"0",
      "ipmdns_protocol":"https",
      "ipmdns_type":"named",
      "dns_force_hybrid":"0",
      "gss_keytab_id":"0",
      "use_update_policy":"0",
      "dnszone_synching":"0",
      "dns_state":"Y",
      "vdns_parent_id":"0",
      "dnszone_allow_update":"admin;",
      "dnszone_allow_query":"",
      "dnszone_allow_transfer":"",
      "dnszone_forwarders":"",
      "dnszone_forward":"default",
      "dnszone_notify":"",
      "dnszone_also_notify":"",
      "dnszone_name_utf":"emea.iras-tp.com",
      "dnszone_id":"31700",
      "row_enabled":"1",
      "dns_type":"ipm",
      "dns_cloud":"0",
      "dnszone_ad_integrated":"0",
      "dnszone_sort_zone":"emea.iras-tp.com",
      "dns_id":"6",
      "dns_name":"dnscom",
      "dnszone_name":"emea.iras-tp.com",
      "dnszone_rev_sort_zone":"com.iras-tp.emea",
      "dnszone_is_rpz":"0",
      "dnszone_type":"master",
      "dnszone_masters":"",
      "dnszone_xfer_done":"Y",
      "dnszone_is_reverse":"0",
      "delayed_delete_time":"0",
      "delayed_create_time":"0",
      "dnszone_order":"0",
      "dnszone_site_name":"Gen",
      "dnszone_site_id":"3",
      "dnszone_class_name":"",
      "dnsview_name":"#",
      "dnsview_id":"0",
      "dnsview_class_name":"",
      "dns_class_name":"",
      "dns_comment":"Niewegein NL-213 ",
      "dns_version":"BIND 9.11.8",
      "vdns_parent_name":"#",
      "ds":"",
      "ip_addr":"8jhg1",
      "multistatus":"",
      "dnszone_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source":"ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
      "dnsview_class_parameters":"",
      "dnsview_class_parameters_properties":"",
      "dns_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dns_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
   },
   { 
      "errno":"0",
      "num_keys":"0",
      "ipmdns_hsm_enabled":"0",
      "ipmdns_protocol":"https",
      "ipmdns_type":"named",
      "dns_force_hybrid":"0",
      "gss_keytab_id":"0",
      "use_update_policy":"0",
      "dnszone_synching":"0",
      "dns_state":"Y",
      "vdns_parent_id":"0",
      "dnszone_allow_update":"admin;",
      "dnszone_allow_query":"",
      "dnszone_allow_transfer":"",
      "dnszone_forwarders":"",
      "dnszone_forward":"default",
      "dnszone_notify":"",
      "dnszone_also_notify":"",
      "dnszone_name_utf":"apac.iras-tp.com",
      "dnszone_id":"31708",
      "row_enabled":"1",
      "dns_type":"ipm",
      "dns_cloud":"0",
      "dnszone_ad_integrated":"0",
      "dnszone_sort_zone":"apac.iras-tp.com",
      "dns_id":"6",
      "dns_name":"dnscom",
      "dnszone_name":"apac.iras-tp.com",
      "dnszone_rev_sort_zone":"com.iras-tp.apac",
      "dnszone_is_rpz":"0",
      "dnszone_type":"master",
      "dnszone_masters":"",
      "dnszone_xfer_done":"Y",
      "dnszone_is_reverse":"0",
      "delayed_delete_time":"0",
      "delayed_create_time":"0",
      "dnszone_order":"0",
      "dnszone_site_name":"Gen",
      "dnszone_site_id":"3",
      "dnszone_class_name":"",
      "dnsview_name":"#",
      "dnsview_id":"0",
      "dnsview_class_name":"",
      "dns_class_name":"",
      "dns_comment":"Niewegein NL-213 ",
      "dns_version":"BIND 9.11.8",
      "vdns_parent_name":"#",
      "ds":"",
      "ip_addr":"56kjhffc1",
      "multistatus":"",
      "dnszone_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source":"ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
      "dnsview_class_parameters":"",
      "dnsview_class_parameters_properties":"",
      "dns_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dns_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
   },
   { 
      "errno":"0",
      "num_keys":"0",
      "ipmdns_hsm_enabled":"0",
      "ipmdns_protocol":"https",
      "ipmdns_type":"named",
      "dns_force_hybrid":"0",
      "gss_keytab_id":"0",
      "use_update_policy":"0",
      "dnszone_synching":"0",
      "dns_state":"Y",
      "vdns_parent_id":"0",
      "dnszone_allow_update":"admin;",
      "dnszone_allow_query":"",
      "dnszone_allow_transfer":"",
      "dnszone_forwarders":"",
      "dnszone_forward":"default",
      "dnszone_notify":"",
      "dnszone_also_notify":"",
      "dnszone_name_utf":"uat.iras-tp.com",
      "dnszone_id":"33045",
      "row_enabled":"1",
      "dns_type":"ipm",
      "dns_cloud":"0",
      "dnszone_ad_integrated":"0",
      "dnszone_sort_zone":"uat.iras-tp.com",
      "dns_id":"6",
      "dns_name":"dnscom",
      "dnszone_name":"uat.iras-tp.com",
      "dnszone_rev_sort_zone":"com.iras-tp.uat",
      "dnszone_is_rpz":"0",
      "dnszone_type":"master",
      "dnszone_masters":"",
      "dnszone_xfer_done":"Y",
      "dnszone_is_reverse":"0",
      "delayed_delete_time":"0",
      "delayed_create_time":"0",
      "dnszone_order":"0",
      "dnszone_site_name":"Gen",
      "dnszone_site_id":"3",
      "dnszone_class_name":"",
      "dnsview_name":"#",
      "dnsview_id":"0",
      "dnsview_class_name":"",
      "dns_class_name":"",
      "dns_comment":"Niewegein NL-213 ",
      "dns_version":"BIND 9.11.8",
      "vdns_parent_name":"#",
      "ds":"",
      "ip_addr":"fghlkj",
      "multistatus":"",
      "dnszone_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
      "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source":"ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
      "dnsview_class_parameters":"",
      "dnsview_class_parameters_properties":"",
      "dns_class_parameters":"ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
      "dns_class_parameters_properties":"ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
   }
]
```

which contains 4 set of values. But when I choose response.length; output is 6700, where it should return "4". What is the javascript code to do it i.e to get number of sets in array and treat each set as a separate array?

Comment: _"output is 6700"_ - Then it's still JSON (a string)

Comment: Try parsing your string to an actual JSON object, this can be done with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @Andreas How to change it to json result and fetch the result? My target is to parse and extract result. So i need the proper length

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Javascript how to parse JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array)

Comment: _<search provider of your choice>_: javascript parse json

Comment: You said `How to change it to json`...but the problem is that it already **is** JSON. That's not what you want. You want to change it **from** JSON **to** a usable JavaScript variable. JSON is a text-only format. It is not the same as a JavaScript object/array. Please make sure you understand the difference.

Comment: @CerebralFart here is the coed i tried.
 var response = request.execute();
var result=response.getBody();
gs.print(result)

var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
gs.print(jsonData.script.length);

Comment: jsonData.length not .script.length after parsing

Comment: `jsonData.script.length` makes no sense there. What is `script` supposed to be? `jsonData` should be an array, according to your example data.

Comment: @DimitriosMatanis nope. here it didnt give result.
Evaluator: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: "script" is not defined.
   Caused by error in script at line 13

     10: gs.print(result)
     11: 
     12: var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
==>  13: gs.print(script.length);

here is result

Comment: I don't know what library you're using to get the data but if you JS `fetch()` then it's trivial to parse it as JSON and then log the length. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pt3q0jwx/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "errno": "0",
    "num_keys": "0",
    "ipmdns_hsm_enabled": "0",
    "ipmdns_protocol": "https",
    "ipmdns_type": "named",
    "dns_force_hybrid": "0",
    "gss_keytab_id": "0",
    "use_update_policy": "0",
    "dnszone_synching": "0",
    "dns_state": "Y",
    "vdns_parent_id": "0",
    "dnszone_allow_update": "admin;",
    "dnszone_allow_query": "",
    "dnszone_allow_transfer": "",
    "dnszone_forwarders": "",
    "dnszone_forward": "default",
    "dnszone_notify": "",
    "dnszone_also_notify": "",
    "dnszone_name_utf": "amec.com",
    "dnszone_id": "31704",
    "row_enabled": "1",
    "dns_type": "ipm",
    "dns_cloud": "0",
    "dnszone_ad_integrated": "0",
    "dnszone_sort_zone": "amec.iras-tp.com",
    "dns_id": "6",
    "dns_name": "dnscom",
    "dnszone_name": "amec.iras-tp.com",
    "dnszone_rev_sort_zone": "com.iras-tp.amec",
    "dnszone_is_rpz": "0",
    "dnszone_type": "master",
    "dnszone_masters": "",
    "dnszone_xfer_done": "Y",
    "dnszone_is_reverse": "0",
    "delayed_delete_time": "0",
    "delayed_create_time": "0",
    "dnszone_order": "0",
    "dnszone_site_name": "Gen",
    "dnszone_site_id": "3",
    "dnszone_class_name": "",
    "dnsview_name": "#",
    "dnsview_id": "0",
    "dnsview_class_name": "",
    "dns_class_name": "",
    "dns_comment": "Niewegein NL-213 ",
    "dns_version": "BIND 9.11.8",
    "vdns_parent_name": "#",
    "ds": "",
    "ip_addr": "fghjj",
    "multistatus": "",
    "dnszone_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source": "ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
    "dnsview_class_parameters": "",
    "dnsview_class_parameters_properties": "",
    "dns_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dns_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
  },
  {
    "errno": "0",
    "num_keys": "0",
    "ipmdns_hsm_enabled": "0",
    "ipmdns_protocol": "https",
    "ipmdns_type": "named",
    "dns_force_hybrid": "0",
    "gss_keytab_id": "0",
    "use_update_policy": "0",
    "dnszone_synching": "0",
    "dns_state": "Y",
    "vdns_parent_id": "0",
    "dnszone_allow_update": "admin;",
    "dnszone_allow_query": "",
    "dnszone_allow_transfer": "",
    "dnszone_forwarders": "",
    "dnszone_forward": "default",
    "dnszone_notify": "",
    "dnszone_also_notify": "",
    "dnszone_name_utf": "emea.iras-tp.com",
    "dnszone_id": "31700",
    "row_enabled": "1",
    "dns_type": "ipm",
    "dns_cloud": "0",
    "dnszone_ad_integrated": "0",
    "dnszone_sort_zone": "emea.iras-tp.com",
    "dns_id": "6",
    "dns_name": "dnscom",
    "dnszone_name": "emea.iras-tp.com",
    "dnszone_rev_sort_zone": "com.iras-tp.emea",
    "dnszone_is_rpz": "0",
    "dnszone_type": "master",
    "dnszone_masters": "",
    "dnszone_xfer_done": "Y",
    "dnszone_is_reverse": "0",
    "delayed_delete_time": "0",
    "delayed_create_time": "0",
    "dnszone_order": "0",
    "dnszone_site_name": "Gen",
    "dnszone_site_id": "3",
    "dnszone_class_name": "",
    "dnsview_name": "#",
    "dnsview_id": "0",
    "dnsview_class_name": "",
    "dns_class_name": "",
    "dns_comment": "Niewegein NL-213 ",
    "dns_version": "BIND 9.11.8",
    "vdns_parent_name": "#",
    "ds": "",
    "ip_addr": "8jhg1",
    "multistatus": "",
    "dnszone_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source": "ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
    "dnsview_class_parameters": "",
    "dnsview_class_parameters_properties": "",
    "dns_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dns_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
  },
  {
    "errno": "0",
    "num_keys": "0",
    "ipmdns_hsm_enabled": "0",
    "ipmdns_protocol": "https",
    "ipmdns_type": "named",
    "dns_force_hybrid": "0",
    "gss_keytab_id": "0",
    "use_update_policy": "0",
    "dnszone_synching": "0",
    "dns_state": "Y",
    "vdns_parent_id": "0",
    "dnszone_allow_update": "admin;",
    "dnszone_allow_query": "",
    "dnszone_allow_transfer": "",
    "dnszone_forwarders": "",
    "dnszone_forward": "default",
    "dnszone_notify": "",
    "dnszone_also_notify": "",
    "dnszone_name_utf": "apac.iras-tp.com",
    "dnszone_id": "31708",
    "row_enabled": "1",
    "dns_type": "ipm",
    "dns_cloud": "0",
    "dnszone_ad_integrated": "0",
    "dnszone_sort_zone": "apac.iras-tp.com",
    "dns_id": "6",
    "dns_name": "dnscom",
    "dnszone_name": "apac.iras-tp.com",
    "dnszone_rev_sort_zone": "com.iras-tp.apac",
    "dnszone_is_rpz": "0",
    "dnszone_type": "master",
    "dnszone_masters": "",
    "dnszone_xfer_done": "Y",
    "dnszone_is_reverse": "0",
    "delayed_delete_time": "0",
    "delayed_create_time": "0",
    "dnszone_order": "0",
    "dnszone_site_name": "Gen",
    "dnszone_site_id": "3",
    "dnszone_class_name": "",
    "dnsview_name": "#",
    "dnsview_id": "0",
    "dnsview_class_name": "",
    "dns_class_name": "",
    "dns_comment": "Niewegein NL-213 ",
    "dns_version": "BIND 9.11.8",
    "vdns_parent_name": "#",
    "ds": "",
    "ip_addr": "56kjhffc1",
    "multistatus": "",
    "dnszone_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source": "ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
    "dnsview_class_parameters": "",
    "dnsview_class_parameters_properties": "",
    "dns_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dns_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
  },
  {
    "errno": "0",
    "num_keys": "0",
    "ipmdns_hsm_enabled": "0",
    "ipmdns_protocol": "https",
    "ipmdns_type": "named",
    "dns_force_hybrid": "0",
    "gss_keytab_id": "0",
    "use_update_policy": "0",
    "dnszone_synching": "0",
    "dns_state": "Y",
    "vdns_parent_id": "0",
    "dnszone_allow_update": "admin;",
    "dnszone_allow_query": "",
    "dnszone_allow_transfer": "",
    "dnszone_forwarders": "",
    "dnszone_forward": "default",
    "dnszone_notify": "",
    "dnszone_also_notify": "",
    "dnszone_name_utf": "uat.iras-tp.com",
    "dnszone_id": "33045",
    "row_enabled": "1",
    "dns_type": "ipm",
    "dns_cloud": "0",
    "dnszone_ad_integrated": "0",
    "dnszone_sort_zone": "uat.iras-tp.com",
    "dns_id": "6",
    "dns_name": "dnscom",
    "dnszone_name": "uat.iras-tp.com",
    "dnszone_rev_sort_zone": "com.iras-tp.uat",
    "dnszone_is_rpz": "0",
    "dnszone_type": "master",
    "dnszone_masters": "",
    "dnszone_xfer_done": "Y",
    "dnszone_is_reverse": "0",
    "delayed_delete_time": "0",
    "delayed_create_time": "0",
    "dnszone_order": "0",
    "dnszone_site_name": "Gen",
    "dnszone_site_id": "3",
    "dnszone_class_name": "",
    "dnsview_name": "#",
    "dnsview_id": "0",
    "dnsview_class_name": "",
    "dns_class_name": "",
    "dns_comment": "Niewegein NL-213 ",
    "dns_version": "BIND 9.11.8",
    "vdns_parent_name": "#",
    "ds": "",
    "ip_addr": "fghlkj",
    "multistatus": "",
    "dnszone_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=inherited,restrict&dnsptr=inherited,restrict",
    "dnszone_class_parameters_inheritance_source": "ipam_replication=real_dns,6&dnsptr=real_dns,6",
    "dnsview_class_parameters": "",
    "dnsview_class_parameters_properties": "",
    "dns_class_parameters": "ipam_replication=1&dnsptr=1",
    "dns_class_parameters_properties": "ipam_replication=set,propagate&dnsptr=set,propagate"
  }
];
var myJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  
  Object.keys(myJSON)
  .forEach(function eachKey(key) { 
   console.log(myJSON[key].dnszone_name_utf)
  });
```

Comment: You're entirely missing the point here. There is no JSON in your example here, just a JS literal array. OP is dealing with a JSON string, not a literal.

Comment: oh, i thought he was looking to check the length of that JSON. Then he need to first parse the string to JSON and check the length

Comment: Here i am posting the entire code i used.

var request = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
request.setEndpoint("https://***/rest/dns_zone_list");
request.setHttpMethod('GET');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
var response = request.execute();
var result=response.getBody();
gs.print(result)

var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
gs.print(jsonData.script.length);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.script.length; i++) {
    var myjsons= jsonData.script[i];
    gs.print(script.errno);
    gs.print(script.num_keys);
}

P.S:changed URL,removed Creds for security concern

Comment: @user6250770 Yes OP wants to check the length. But once it's parsed, it isn't JSON anymore. OP knows in theory how to check the length, but they're having an  issue understanding how to parse it and then correctly check the length of the right variable. To have relevance, your example needs to show the whole process really.

Comment: @user6250770 console.log which worked and gave result as expected in Postman, here i am posting the coed in servicenow and the output is as shown. Code behaviour seems entirely different from postman and servicenow

Comment: @impika in that code in your comment just above, you're still using `jsonData.script`...and as per your example code, `script` doesn't exist. Just use `jsonData.length`...we keep telling you! Is there something you don't understand about what we're saying?

Comment: @ADyson . Sorry i posted that here by mistake, i removed it and still it didn't work

Comment: @impika you posted the question which leading us to wrong way . i just updated my answer. Check that  whether it's helpful or not. If not, Please explain briefly what you really wants to achieve.

Comment: @user6250770 i want to achieve extract each key value pair from the response

Comment: @impika please check the edited answer now. I have updated code with fetching value of a key "dnszone_name_utf" from all arrays in the JSON .

Comment: @impika "still it didn't work"...didn't work how exactly? What goes wrong? You know, it would be better if you edit your original post to include the code you've got right now, and the error / problem you're currently experiencing. Then everyone can see clearly.

Comment: @user6250770 finally var = JSON.parse(result); alone worked. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson finally var = JSON.parse(result); alone worked. Thanks

Comment: @impika are you sure? Writing `var =` followed by anything will cause a syntax error, because `var` is a keyword. Did you forget to include the variable name? Also, that line alone won't tell you the length of the array, as you originally requested.

Comment: @impika the posted answer should work for you. then please make that answer as accepted solution.