# Array of object inside method parameter while using the map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to pass array inside method while using the map in javascript?

```
<ul class="details">
    ${
        speedRecords.map(speed =>  `<li>${speed.name}<span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showModalWithTopic(${speed.name} , ${speed.topics} )">${speed.total}</a></span></li>`)
        .join('')
    }
</ul>

speedRecords=[
    {
        total: 6
        name: "Wolks"
        topics: [
            {
                property1 : "one",
                property2 : "two"
            },
            {
                property1 : "55",
                property2 : "66"
            },
            {
                property1 : "11",
                property2 : "22"
            ]
    },
    {
        total: 5
        name: "Honda"
        topics: [
            {
                property1 : "one",
                property2 : "two"
            },
            {
                property1 : "55",
                property2 : "66"
            },
            {
                property1 : "11",
                property2 : "22"
            ]
    }
]
```

The line  `function showModalWithTopic(name, topics){}` does do some other operation but topics always return to me as Object object.

When I look at this `showModalWithTopic(${speed.name} , ${speed.topics})` method parameter is not created in proper way because it contains `('Honda' , [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] )`

See also:
[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991805/javascript-how-to-parse-json-array/9991872 answer your question?

Comment: Are you using some templating library? `<ul class="details">` followed by `${` is not what you would expect in HTML, nor JavaScript, but looks like some templating framework. Please clarify.

Comment: I have a function ```function handleNewUser(speedRecords) {}``` where i am using this ```<ul class="details">``` setting this using innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna do something like this :

```js
 
speedRecords= [{
    total: 5,
    name: "Honda",
    topics: [{
      property1 : "one",
      property2 : "two"
        }, {
      property1 : "55",
      property2 : "66"
        }, {
      property1 : "11",
      property2 : "22"
    }]
}];

document.getElementById('displayElement').innerHTML = speedRecords.map(speed =>  `<li>
            ${speed.name}
        <span>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
             onclick="showModalWithTopic(${speed.name} , ${speed.topics})">
             ${speed.total}
          </a>
        </span></li>`);
```

```html
<ul class="details">
    <div id="displayElement"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have created the same thing, you can check you do also have the same error ```showModalWithTopic()``` contains Object object, instead of containing list of object

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_display.asp